# Pie Chart expanding on each refresh

Tags: extjs, google-visualization

I have a Google pie chart which refresh every 5 second.
On every refresh,pie chart is expanding.
Then after 5-6 refresh it disappears.
I am facing this problem  in all browsers.Please advise

```
/**
* Function for Google PieChart
**/   
    function drawVisualization() {
      // Create and populate the data table.
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        // dynamic data
      ]);

      // Create and draw the visualization.
      new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
    }

    /*
     *Extjs Pannel for Pie Chart
    **/
    {xtype:'label',
             id:'pannelid',
             width:'100%',
             html : '<table width="100%"><tr><tr> <td> <div id="visualization" align="left"> </div></td></tr></table>'
    }

    /**
     *For refreshing Pie Chart every 5 sec
    **/
    setInterval(function(){
    drawVisualization();
    },5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't explicitly set dimensions in the chart's options or on it's container div in CSS, then you get a process that looks something like this:

fetch container dimensions -> use as chart dimensions -> browser expands container due to margins/padding -> redraw -> fetch (larger) container dimensions -> repeat

You have to explicitly set the dimensions of the chart either in the chart's options or in the CSS of the container element in order to fix this, eg:

```
new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
        title: "So, how was your day?",
        height: 300,
        width: 400
    });
```

or:

```
#visualization: {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

When you call the drawVisualization function multiple times, you are creating new DataTables and chart objects over and over again, which might not be getting garbage collected, so you could be having problems with that.  It is a better idea to refresh the data in the DataTable and redraw the existing chart with the new data rather than create new objects every time:

```
drawVisualization () {
    var data = ...;
    var chart = ...;
    chart.draw(...);

    setInterval(function () {
        // refresh data and redraw chart
    }, 5000);
}
```